# How can i manipulate the host application using my plugins in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, plugins

I created a simple application which can host plugins.
If Plugins provide dependent services its all OK and there is no problem,But when it comes to creating a plugin which manipulates the host itself (e.g changing its `BackColor`,adding text to its `TextBox` and etc) I cant seem to find a solution for it!
Since every method i tried would not work because of the circular dependency as it seems.
First i tried to create some public `Setters` and `Getters` inside my host application , when i tried to add it as a reference to my `IpluginInterface` it said due to circular dependency you cant,
I tried a middle class to implement the setters and getters for the host application , again i faced the same error .
What can i do to avoid this error and manipulate the host application?

Comment: I seem to have mistakenly edited your post, so it now has the edit from my answer below in it :/ Mods to fix please, just reject the suggested edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a third project called "Interfaces" then place interfaces to the main application in there. When you instanciate the plug in, pass in a reference to the main application via that interface. This prevents the circular references.

The main project and the plug in can both reference the "Interfaces" project.

EDIT: Here is a complete code example. Now, of course, I've put everything in one file for simplicity, but I've added comments about where each part would normally reside. You mentioned parameters being of types that the plug in doesn't know about. In that case, simply add a new interface to the interfaces project and make the parameter derive from that interface.

To run this, create a winforms project and paste the lot into a new class. Then delete the old form and Program.cs files.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    // This is the program start. Probably the place that would have loaded the plug ins.
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }

    //Form goes in project one and has a reference to Interfaces.
    public class MainForm : Form, IMainForm
    {
        private TextBox _textBox;
        private IPlugIn _thePlugIn;
        private Button _aButton;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _thePlugIn = ObtainPlugInsThroughMagic();
        }

        private IPlugIn ObtainPlugInsThroughMagic()
        {
            // So this would usually go off and load some DLLs and then instantiate the IPlugIn objects
            // We're cheating.
            var plugin = new MyPlugIn();
            plugin.Initialise(this);
            return plugin;
        }

        public void SetTextBoxValueFromPlugIn(string newText)
        {
            _textBox.Text = newText;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            _textBox = new TextBox();
            _aButton = new Button();
            SuspendLayout();

            _aButton.Location = new Point(20, 50);
            _aButton.Size = new Size(100, 25);
            _aButton.TabIndex = 1;
            _aButton.Click += AButtonClick;
            _aButton.Text = "Fire plug in";
            _textBox.Location = new Point(20, 10);            
            _textBox.Size = new Size(260, 20);
            _textBox.TabIndex = 0;

            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 100);
            Controls.Add(_textBox);
            Controls.Add(_aButton);
            Text = "Main form";
            ResumeLayout(false);
            PerformLayout();
        }

        private void AButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _thePlugIn.MakePlugInDoItsStuff();
        }
    }

    #region interfaces go in the new Interfaces project.

    public interface IMainForm
    {
        void SetTextBoxValueFromPlugIn(string newText);
    }

    public interface IPlugIn
    {
        void Initialise(IMainForm mainForm);
        void MakePlugInDoItsStuff();
    }

    #endregion

    // The plug in goes in the plug in project and has a reference to Interfaces.

    public class MyPlugIn : IPlugIn
    {
        public IMainForm MainForm { get; private set; }

        public void Initialise(IMainForm mainForm)
        {
            MainForm = mainForm;
        }

        public void MakePlugInDoItsStuff()
        {
            MainForm.SetTextBoxValueFromPlugIn("Text set from plug in");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this right now , But the problem is , in my Interface i need to specify teh parameters type , and here one type is my HostForm, and for Interface to accept it i need to reference the HostApplication project and this fails.

Comment: Yes, but if you create another interface which represents the host form, and keep that interface in the third project you should be fine. The trick is not to use base types. You don't actually want to pass the main form through as a form, you really want to pass it through as an interface which exposes specific methods like "ChangeBackground" and so on. So tl;dr, use interfaces for the parameters too.

Comment: Sorry cant get it through my head! :-/ , Is there any kind of example you could help me with? I am really puzzled !
Basically that method of yours also would need me to pass the form anyway so that the internal setters and getters can be used:-/ right?

Comment: Sure, I'll produce a little sample. The important thing to remember is that you need to forget that your main form is a "main form". It becomes hidden behind an interface.

Comment: Thanks a billion:) I got it all now :)